# SystemVerilog replace connection with UVC using bind

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have two modules connected together via an AXI interface, with module A being the master and module B being the slave, as depicted below:

```
  _________________________________________ 
 | top.v                                   |
 |  __________                 __________  |
 | |          |               |          | |
 | |          |<------------->|          | |
 | | module A |      AXI      | module B | |
 | |          |<------------->|          | |
 | |__________|               |__________| |
 |_________________________________________|
```

I want to "replace" this connection with an AXI UVC so my UVC can receive the AXI request from module A, modify it, and send the modified request to module B. I also want to inject requests to module B from my UVC, so module A wouldn't know about them, so it would look like this:

```
  _________________________________________ 
 | top.v                                   |
 |  __________                 __________  |
 | |          |      ___      |          | |
 | |          |<--->|   |<--->|          | |
 | | module A | AXI |UVC| AXI | module B | |
 | |          |<--->|___|<--->|          | |
 | |__________|               |__________| |
 |_________________________________________|
```

The caveat is that I'm not able to modify the RTL files that instantiate modules A, B, and the interface (anything in top.v). So I'd like to use `bind` to bind the UVC to the AXI interface, but I'm not sure if this can work as expected. My concern is that since modules A and B are still connected, they will still toggle each other's ports, e.g. if module A toggles AWVALID, it will still toggle module B's input AWVALID. Is it possible that the bind can "override" these signals?

Comment: The bind statement places an instance of the module/interface into a desired place. It cannot patch connections. So, you cannot do it with just a bind.To override signals you can use verilog 'force/release'.

Comment: If the ports are wires then force/release are not going to work. You may want to work with your designers to make them of type 'reg'. You can refer to this paper: https://www.verilab.com/files/verification_prowess_with_uvm_harness.pdf for how to use force/release in this context.

Answer (score 0):

`bind` cannot break a connection, it can only add to it. But there is no reason you can't modify or override the existing RTL unless it's encrypted.